# fullcalendar v5.3 incomplete border

Tags: css, border, fullcalendar-5

Can someone suggest or help with the border on full calendar V5.3. Border is incomplete on both the top and left.  CSS worked in V4, can't see where/if this changed in V5.

```
#calendar {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: auto;
  margin: 60px auto;
          

font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
}
.fc td,
.fc th {
   border: 1px solid darkgreen;
       }
```

thanks

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oceantrl/9bwpjv5t/)

Comment: did you try adding !important to the rule so it overrides rules on other elements (e.g. container elements)?

Comment: @Dyson, now don't I feel foolish...that does seem to have done it (could have sworn I tried that!!)  Thank you